# How to detect if the mouse click choosed an color displayed bellow

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to know the command to detect if the user has clicked on an asked color in tkinter, here's my program:

```
from tkinter import*
from random import*

fenetre=Tk()
fenetre.title('Jeu Chlepko Peter')
fenetre.geometry('500x280+500+280')

zone=Canvas(fenetre,width=500,height=100)
zone.grid(row=3, rowspan=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
zone.create_rectangle(0,0,500,200,fill='Grey')
couleurs=['Red','Green','Blue','Yellow','White','Purple','Pink','Black','Cyan','Orange']
shuffle(couleurs)



def jouer():
    zone.total=0
    zone.create_rectangle(0,0,500,200,fill='Grey')
    zone.alea=randint(0,4)
    zone.create_oval(0,100,100,0,fill=couleurs[zone.alea])
    zone.create_oval(200,100,100,0,fill='Blue')
    zone.create_oval(300,100,200,0,fill='White')
    zone.create_oval(400,100,300,0,fill='Black')
    zone.create_oval(500,100,400,0,fill='Orange')



bouton_jouer=Button(fenetre,text="Lancer le jeu",command=jouer)
bouton_jouer.grid(row=1,column=1)

description=Label(fenetre,text='')
description.grid(row=2,column=1)



bouton_quitter=Button(fenetre,text='Quitter', command=fenetre.destroy)
bouton_quitter.grid(row=7,column=1)

description=Label(fenetre,text='Cliquez sur la couleur demandée')
description.grid(row=0, column=1)

enter code here

fenetre.mainloop()
```

I will be very pleased if you could respond me

Answer (score 0):

I've added a onClick function to your code. This function receives from tkinter which widget called it along with some information like the x,y coordinates.
I've used this to find the nearest object in the Canvas to where the user clicked.
Then I use itemcget to tell what color that object is and print the color to the terminal output. You can then use this for whatever you need

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *

fenetre=Tk()
fenetre.title('Jeu Chlepko Peter')
fenetre.geometry('500x280+500+280')

zone=Canvas(fenetre,width=500,height=100)
zone.grid(row=3, rowspan=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
zone.create_rectangle(0,0,500,200,fill='Grey')
couleurs=['Red','Green','Blue','Yellow','White','Purple','Pink','Black','Cyan','Orange']
shuffle(couleurs)


def onClick(event):
    item = event.widget.find_closest(event.x,event.y)
    color = event.widget.itemcget(item,'fill')
    print(color)

def jouer():
    zone.total=0
    zone.create_rectangle(0,0,500,200,fill='Grey')
    zone.alea=randint(0,4)
    zone.create_oval(0,100,100,0,fill=couleurs[zone.alea])
    zone.create_oval(200,100,100,0,fill='Blue')
    zone.create_oval(300,100,200,0,fill='White')
    zone.create_oval(400,100,300,0,fill='Black')
    zone.create_oval(500,100,400,0,fill='Orange')



bouton_jouer=Button(fenetre,text="Lancer le jeu",command=jouer)
bouton_jouer.grid(row=1,column=1)

description=Label(fenetre,text='')
description.grid(row=2,column=1)

zone.bind('<Button-1>',onClick)

bouton_quitter=Button(fenetre,text='Quitter', command=fenetre.destroy)
bouton_quitter.grid(row=7,column=1)

description=Label(fenetre,text='Cliquez sur la couleur demandée')
description.grid(row=0, column=1)

fenetre.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand that you want to choose 4 colors from the `couleurs` list in each game when the user click the `Lancer le jeu` button.  Then you want to randomly choose one from  the 4 chosen colors and ask the user to click on the correct color.

Below is a modified version of your posted code to achieve the goal:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint, shuffle

fenetre=Tk()
fenetre.title('Jeu Chlepko Peter')
fenetre.geometry('550x280+500+280')

zone=Canvas(fenetre,width=550,height=100)
zone.grid(row=3, rowspan=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
zone.create_rectangle(0,0,550,200,fill='Grey')

couleurs=['Red','Green','Blue','Yellow','White','Purple','Pink','Black','Cyan','Orange']

def on_circle_click(event):
  # get the item being clicked
  item = event.widget.find_withtag(CURRENT)[0]
  # get its color
  color = event.widget.itemcget(item, 'fill')
  print(color)
  if color == couleurs[zone.alea]:
    # do whatever you want
    print('correct color selected')
  else:
    print('oops! try again!')

# bind mouse click event to items with tag 'circle' only
zone.tag_bind('circle', '<Button-1>', on_circle_click)

def jouer():
  shuffle(couleurs) # rearrange the colors
  zone.alea = randint(0, 3) # get a random number between 0 and 3
  # remove existing circles
  zone.delete('random', 'circle')
  # create the circle with target color
  zone.create_oval(0,100,100,0,fill=couleurs[zone.alea], tags='random')
  # create circles with the first four colors in the color list with tag 'circle'
  zone.create_oval(250,100,150,0,fill=couleurs[0], tag='circle')
  zone.create_oval(350,100,250,0,fill=couleurs[1], tag='circle')
  zone.create_oval(450,100,350,0,fill=couleurs[2], tag='circle')
  zone.create_oval(550,100,450,0,fill=couleurs[3], tag='circle')

bouton_jouer=Button(fenetre,text="Lancer le jeu",command=jouer)
bouton_jouer.grid(row=1,column=1)

description=Label(fenetre,text='')
description.grid(row=2,column=1)

bouton_quitter=Button(fenetre,text='Quitter', command=fenetre.destroy)
bouton_quitter.grid(row=7,column=1)

description=Label(fenetre,text='Cliquez sur la couleur demandée')
description.grid(row=0, column=1)

fenetre.mainloop()
```